# Stack based allocation not recommended?

Tags: c, abi, libmemcached

The [libmemcached documentation](http://docs.libmemcached.org/memcached_create.html#) has this note:

> You may wish to avoid using memcached_create(3) or memcached_clone(3)
>   with a stack based allocation. The most common issues related to ABI
>   safety involve heap allocated structures.

How do I have to understand it? Stands in this case ABI for `Application Binary Interface`? I would like to provide the pointer to the struct for `memcached_clone()` from a variable in the local function scope. Is it safe?

Example - is this code OK?

```
foo()
{
   memcached_st clone_memc;

   memcached_clone(&clone_memc, master_memc);

   // some memcache function calls (get/set)
   ...

   memcached_free(&clone_memc);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ABI stands for `application binary interface`.
I can think of three reasons to avoid stack allocations. In ascending order of relevance:
**Stack smashing** on overflow may be more straightforward to exploit than heap overflow.
**Lifetime of allocation** ends when the scope of the creating function is left, not keeping this in mind this is a fairly common error for C beginners.
**Stack size limits** are generally rather small (~8kb), allocating significant amounts of storage on the stack may overflow it.

Comment: That far it does not affect me.This question was asked because I am using memcached in MySQL UDF and once getting used to C++ it is a pain to write in pure C